# JS/JQuery - Remove space from input field if it is the first and/or last character

Tags: javascript, jquery, search

I have a site search (using Examine & Razor) that breaks if a space character is the first or last (or both) character in a search query. For example "hello" & "hello world" both work fine, but " hello" & "hello " don't. Is it possible to remove any spaces such as these before the input field is submitted using JS/JQuery?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is JQuery.trim()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Answer (score 2):

Try using this regular expression for your search strings:

```
// presume searchStr = '" hello"' or '"hello "' or '" hello world   "'
searchStr.replace(/(")\s+|\s+(")/g,'"'); //=> "hello" or "hello world"
```

Considering the answer of your choice, the quaotation marks (`"`) are not included? In that case `trim` would be sufficient. In non jquery script:

```
searchStr.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,'');
```